# Batch script crashes when PIPE special character is used in password

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My test.bat crashes when user enters PIPE ('|') as one of the characters in password

**Code:**

```
Set vAppPoolUser=
Set /p vAppPoolUser= Enter MicroStrategyWebPool user name (domain\username): 

Echo.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set vAppPoolUserPswd=
 set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'MicroStrategyWebPool password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set "vAppPoolUserPswd=%%p"
Echo !vAppPoolUserPswd!
Echo.
```

------------------Another block which validates---------------------

```
REM verify user credentials
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set vCredenvalid=
Set "vpsCommand=Powershell -Command "(new-object directoryservices.directoryentry '','%vAppPoolUser%','%vAppPoolUserPswd%').psbase.name -ne $nul"" 
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%vpsCommand%`) do set vCredenvalid=%%p
Echo !vCredenvalid!
if %vCredenvalid%==False ( 
            call :ColorTextMain 0C "Incorrect username or password"
            Echo.


REM verify user credentials
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set vCredenvalid=
Set "vpsCommand=Powershell -Command "(new-object directoryservices.directoryentry '','%vAppPoolUser%','!vAppPoolUserPswd!').psbase.name -ne $nul"" 
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%vpsCommand%`) do set vCredenvalid=%%p
Echo !vCredenvalid!
if !vCredenvalid!==False ( 
            call :ColorTextMain 0C "Incorrect username or password"
            Echo.
goto :readIISUser
) 
echo.
echo Credentials Validated......
echo.
echo Applicaiton message.......Credentials Validated >>%vLog_FileLocation%


REM set apppool user
Echo Application Message.....Setting MicroStrategyWebPool user >>%vLog_FileLocation%
Echo Setting MicroStrategyWebPool user
"%vAppcmdpath%\appcmd.exe" set config /section:applicationPools /[name='MicroStrategyWebPool'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='MicroStrategyWebPool'].processModel.userName:%vAppPoolUser% /[name='MicroStrategyWebPool'].processModel.password:!vAppPoolUserPswd!  >>%vLog_FileLocation%
REM restart appoool
"%vAppcmdpath%\appcmd.exe" recycle apppool /apppool.name:MicroStrategyWebPool
```

**Output:**

Enter WebPool user name (domain\username): testUser

WebPool password: {}|

**Crashes when I hit Enter after the password**

Comment: escape pipe with `^` as in `^|`

Comment: Can you please help how can I do that in the code above while accepting input from user? I am new to batch

Comment: yeah, let me post an answer.

Comment: Why don't you just use Powershell for the entire script?

Comment: Its a big chunk of code. So I have just posted the ones relevant to my scenario.

Comment: ok, so then please do what I said in my last comment....... set all instances of `%vAppPoolUserPswd%` to `!vAppPoolUserPswd!`

Comment: You have additional problems with the code you added to your question. You need to learn when you have to use delayed expansion for your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape special characters using `^` for some and `%` for others.

For this however you need only nee the magic of `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p "pass=password: "
!pass!
```

In this case I enter password `pass|word` and it will echo `passw|word`

I cannot test your actual example, but your code should be something in this line:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledalayedexpansion
Set vAppPoolUser=
Set /p "vAppPoolUser=Enter WebPool user name (domain\username): "

Echo.
set vAppPoolUserPswd=
 set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'WebPool password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set "vAppPoolUserPswd=%%p"
Echo !vAppPoolUserPswd!
```

**EDIT**
As for the escaping of the other characters question in the comments. Generally most other special characters are handles by `enabledelayedexpansion`, but you typically need to escape and `!` and sometimes `^` so after you set the variable:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set "vAppPoolUserPswd=%%p"
set "vAppPoolUserPswd=!vAppPoolUserPswd:^^=^^!"
set "vAppPoolUserPswd=!vAppPoolUserPswd:^^!=^^!!"
echo !vAppPoolUserPswd!
```

from there you need to replace any `%vAppPoolUserPswd%` variables with `!vAppPoolUserPswd!` for `delayedexpansion` to do it's thing.